# jQuery: trigger click() doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

Why clicking on `trigger1` and `trigger2` doesn't fire click on `open` ?

```
<a id="trigger1" href="#" onclick="jQuery('#open').trigger('click');">trigger1</a>  
<a id="trigger2" href="#" onclick="jQuery('#open').click();">trigger2</a>
<a id="open" href="http://google.com">open</a>
```

Using [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) (`trigger3`) doesn't work too:

```
<a id="trigger3" href="#">trigger3</a>
```

...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
  jQuery('#trigger3').bind('click', function(){
      jQuery('#open').html('to be fired'); /* works */
      jQuery('#open').click();        
  });

  jQuery('#trigger3').click(function(){
      jQuery('#open').html('to be fired'); /* works */
      jQuery('#open').click();
  });
});
```

Comment: why do you use inline javascript?

Comment: Wait, does trigger3 work or not?

Comment: `trigger3` doesn't fire click() on `open`, but changing content of `open` works

Comment: remove `onclick="...." ` from both links

Comment: @marioosh it is not a good programming practice to have inline code. You cannot separate it to an external file, minimize it and at the you have to make changes to all the files if somthing changes. Put your js to an external file and import it at the head of the page.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's important to clarify that doing `jQuery('#open').click()` does not execute the href attribute of an anchor tag so you will not be redirected.  It executes the `onclick` event for `#open` which is not defined.

You can accomplish the redirect and the ability to cause it with your original `jQuery('#open').click()` code by giving `#open` a click event:

```
jQuery('#open').click( function (e) {
  window.location.href = this.href;
});
```

Comment: Finally found this one that helped me complete a task of trying to use a button element to trigger a mailto link. Thanks Jake.

Answer (score 7):

From what your code looks like, you want when a user clicks on link one or two *(trigger 1 or 2)* you want the link in `open` to be followed?

If this is the case, `.click()` isn't actually the function you want, in fact jQuery doesn't seem to offer a method of directly clicking on an anchor element. What it will do is trigger any event's which are attached to an element.

Take a look at this example:

```
<a id="trigger" href="#" onclick="$('#open').click();">trigger</a>
<a id="open" href="http://google.com">open</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#open').click(function(){
    alert('I just got clicked!'); 
});
```

[**Try it here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5EfpD/)

So there is an event attached to the element with the ID `open` that simply alerts to say it was clicked. Clicking on the trigger link simply triggers the click event on the element with the ID `open`. So it's not going to do what you want! *It will fire any events but it won't actually follow the link*
*I removed the 2nd trigger because `.click()` is just a proxy for `.trigger('click')` so they do the same thing!*

So to trigger an actual click on an anchor, you will have to do a little more work. To make this slightly more reuseable I would change your HTML a little *(I'll expain why in a moment)*:

```
<a href="#" class="trigger" rel="#open">trigger google</a>
<a id="open" href="http://google.com">google</a>
<br/><br/>
<a href="#" class="trigger" rel="#bing">trigger bing</a>
<a id="bing" href="http://bing.com">bing</a>
```

jQuery *(shortest)*:

```
$('.trigger').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = $($(this).attr('rel')).attr('href');
});
```

[**Try it here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5EfpD/1/)

OR:

```
$('.trigger').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var obj = $(this).attr('rel');
    var link = $(obj).attr('href');
    window.location = link;
});
```

[**Try it here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5EfpD/2/)

Basically any link you want to follow another element add the `class="trigger"` to, this way it is re-useable. In the element you have added the `class` to, add a `rel="#element-to-be-clicked"` this will allow you to setup multiple clicks on different links.

- So you are now capturing any clicks on an element with the `class="trigger"`
- Finding the element you wanted to be clicked on `rel="#element-to-be-clicked"`
- Getting the `href` address from the element
- Changing the windows location to the new link

Comment: Thanks for **in-depth** explanation, Scroobler. Vote up:)

Comment: Actually, your "jQuery (shortest)" version can be compressed even further. Simply use `$(this).off('click')[0].click()` instead of the `window.location` line. This will unset the click event handler from within itself, then trigger a DOM-level click on the `.trigger` element. A DOM-level click *will* follow the link.

Answer (score 2):

try with removing `onclick="jQuery('#open').click();"`

Also try to putting `$('#trigger1')` you are using `jQuery('#trigger3')`

On [JSFIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/rMHeM/3/).

Answer (score 2):

you are binding event `click` to `#trigger3` *twice*. remove one of them

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
  jQuery('#trigger3').bind('click', function(){
      jQuery('#open').text('to be fired'); /* works */
      jQuery('#open').click();        
  });

  jQuery('#trigger3').click(function(){
      jQuery('#open').text('to be fired'); /* works */
      jQuery('#open').click();
  });
});
```

jQuery('#open').html('to be fired'); will change the  to just a text. That's why the 2nd select doesn't work.

Comment: i've put `jQuery('#open').html('...')` to show does `jQuery('#open')` works only. It doesn't make a deal with `jQuery('#open').click();`.

Answer (score 0):

There is 3 types of links depending of the `href` content :

1) The `href` is a url
2) The `href` is a javascript call like "javascript:"
3) The `href` is useless ("#", "javascript:void(0)", ...), the function is directly bound on the link

That's why I make this little plugin to call the good method :

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.triggerClick = function() {
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      //No useful link into href, try to call js click
      if(href.indexOf('#') == 0 || href.indexOf('javascript:void(') == 0 || href == '') {
         $(this).click();
      //JS call
      } else if(href.indexOf('javascript:') == 0) {
         eval(href);
      //URL
      } else {
         document.location.href = href;
      }
    };
  })( jQuery );
```

To call it, just use `$('DOMelement').triggerClick()`.
Hope this could help.
(This plugin is a prototype. Thank's to tell me if there is some errors...)