# trigger a click on a anchor link

Tags: jquery, triggers, click, anchor

I have a collection of links with thumbnails that match them. I need to load these thumbnails as divs with the background image set to them. I'm using a single image that has all thumbnails in them, so I can't just load the images as images. Clicking the image should do the same as clicking the link though, I made a JSFiddle to show what I mean (and to show the problem):

[the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6FJ3/)

When I click the two links in there a new window is opened which has the site I want. But when I click the thumbnails I can't get a click on the link triggered.

Clicking of the link will have extra functionality (stats), so I prefer to trigger a click on the link over binding the same custom function to both the anchors and the divs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you just place the `<a>` arround the div so you can click the whole div?

Comment: @manuelvanRijn: that's indeed a good workaround. I'll have to switch some things around in my layout, but that just might work nicely, thanks!

Comment: it doesn't explain why the event isn't triggered though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hiya  **Working demo here:** http://jsfiddle.net/f6FJ3/19/

for the trigger reason read this : [jQuery: trigger click() doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577555/jquery-trigger-click-doesnt-work)

`It's important to clarify that doing jQuery('#open').click() does not execute the href attribute of an anchor tag so you will not be redirected. It executes the onclick event for #open which is not defined.`

below code will get the desired output of window getting open on image click.

**JQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tmb').click(function(){
        var target=$(this).parent().find("a");

        $("#debug").text("clicked "+target.text());
        //target.triggerHandler('click');
        window.open(target.attr('href'));

    });
});​
```

Hope this helps, cheers!

Answer (score 7):

In HTML4 the click event was defined only for the input element and some browser, most notably FF, [strictly followed the specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.click). However HTML5 the game changed and any modern browser implements this functionality, **but** jQuery still has a special case for this event (extract from [jquery trigger method](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js)):

```
if ( !onlyHandlers && !event.isDefaultPrevented() ) {

    if ( (!special._default || special._default.apply( elem.ownerDocument, data ) === false) && !(type === "click" && jQuery.nodeName( elem, "a" )) && jQuery.acceptData( elem ) ) {

    // Call a native DOM method on the target with the same name name as the event.
```

As a workaround you can change your code from:

```
target.trigger("click");
```

to

```
target.get(0).click();
```