# jquery ui-dialog confirm button issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-click-event

Here is some Html + jQuery ui dialog code genereated by asp.net for the browser ..

to my eyes it looks fine but the issue is, confirm button triggers click event for the link with the class specified, although the event does not get triggered.

[Update: I changed the "$(".lDel_23").click();" to document.location.href= "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ListView_Sections$ctrl1$LinkButton_Delete','')" and it called the function .. so the problem seems to be the click trigger not able to work correctly with the href of the link set to a javascript method .. although trying the manual click works the jQuery click trigger calling doesnt .. does that make any sense ???? ]

```
    <a href="#" id="aDel_23"></a>
    <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListView_Sections_ctrl1_LinkButton_Delete" title="Delete" class="lDel_23" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ListView_Sections$ctrl1$LinkButton_Delete','')"></a>
     <div id="dialog_23" title="Confirm Delete">
           Delete Section [section name]
     </div>

     <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#dialog_23").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    width: 400
                });
                // Link to open the dialog
                $("#aDel_23").click(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#dialog_23").dialog({
                        buttons: {
                            'Confirm': function() {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                                $(".lDel_23").click();
                            },
                            'Cancel': function() {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    $('#dialog_23').dialog("open");
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the $(".lDel_23").click(); to occur before  $(this).dialog('close'); ?

Comment: tried and its the same, tried another javascript code instead that redirects to another page to make sure the code runs correctly, it worked ! only problem is that click even doesn't get triggered after the call !

Comment: You mean, that server click handler doesn't triggered? Show your markup

Comment: this is the html code after its generated, forget about server markup my issue is a 'client side'

Comment: Do you render this script in each ItemTemplate?

Comment: yes Yuriy, it changes the script with the id of each row so that everything is in correct shape for the HTML to run flawlessly, the solution is as (thanks to) Tallmaris said exactly, all i had to do is use the native Javascript click trigger instead of the jQuery click function and it worked pretty good !

Comment: @a7mad.3ezz, in my opinion, it's not very well solution to render script for dialog with each item.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18480/discussion-between-yuriy-rozhovetskiy-and-a7mad-3ezz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it is a bit more fiddly to trigger a link on an "a" tag. See if this questions helps out: [trigger a click on a anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904170/trigger-a-click-on-a-anchor-link)

Basically change this: `$(".lDel_23").click();` to `$(".lDel_23").get(0).click();`

Comment: thank you very much, it worked fine .. I find it odd to have to do it this way though !

Comment: Yes it's strange. The difference is that the left `click()` is jQuery code, while the working one is normal Javascript (element native click trigger I mean). The linked SO question and answers will give you all the info you need :)