# Creating a javascript function to make a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make it so that when a track completes playing it automatically calls a javascript function which clicks the next track button so that the playlist continues to play. So far i have:

```
function next() {
    $("#nextTrack").click();
}
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything when it is called, anyone know where i am going wrong?

Comment: You need jQuery Trigger http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Is it working when you click on element with id nextTrack?

Comment: @DeepakKamat `click()` is shorthand for `trigger('click')`, see http://api.jquery.com/click/#click

Comment: Ohh, then it might be some other problem.

Comment: @Sushil yes because that is an <a> tag with the parameters in i need to play the next song. i want to create a function that when i click something else it effectively clicks that <a> tag, that way i can implement it into the complete field for cfmediaplayer

Comment: You need to post all your code, not just this function.

Comment: I don't know if jQuery always has attempted to execute the event on the DOM element when using `trigger`, but does `$("#nextTrack")[0].click();` do anything different? I'm pretty sure the DOM event should be triggered with your code, but mine's just an attempt...

Comment: Either next() is never getting called by your javascript or the anchor link does not have the id="nextTrack".

Comment: @Ian yes the [0] worked perfectly! This should now be fine to put into my code :) thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to trigger the `click` event on the DOM element itself is with:

```
$("#nextTrack")[0].click();
```

This gets the first (only) DOM element matched (removes it from the jQuery wrapper) and calls the native `click` method.

The only reasoning I can provide for this is because `trigger` doesn't (or hasn't, in past versions) attempted to call the native method. I swear in the most recent version, I can use `.trigger("click")` (same as `.click()`) and it will effectively click the element...executing native any click handlers and jQuery handlers as well.

`trigger` is tricky because jQuery stores any event handlers bound with `jQuery.on`, `jQuery.bind`, etc. in a special place. When the native event is fired, or `.trigger("event_name")` is used, all those special handlers are executed. But for some reason, the native event isn't *always* triggered (as you seem to have found out). I'm not sure if it's because of the version of jQuery or the event type.

**UPDATE:**

The reason this is happening is because jQuery treats `<a>` specially when using `.trigger("event_name")`, specifically for the `click` event.

After blabbering with the stuff above, I decided to look into the jQuery source code for `trigger`. In the end, the native DOM method is called, with `elem[ type ]();`. But it only gets to this point under certain conditions...these are the conditions (among other nested `if` statements):

```
if ( (!special._default || special._default.apply( elem.ownerDocument, data ) === false) &&
    !(type === "click" && jQuery.nodeName( elem, "a" )) && jQuery.acceptData( elem ) ) {
```

And I'm guessing that specifically, the part `!(type === "click" && jQuery.nodeName( elem, "a" ))` is what prevents it in your case, because the element you're targeting is `<a>`, and it's the `click` event.

**DEMO:** Here's basically just something mimicking your code in a simpler fashion: http://jsfiddle.net/EjVMY/ - notice how the initial `console.log` on load doesn't execute (because of the `trigger`). But as soon as you **actually** click on the event, the `console.log` does execute. I found that replacing the `<a>` with a `<div>` changes the behavior - it logs on load.

Of course, if I had just Googled it in the first place, I would've found: [trigger a click on a anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904170/trigger-a-click-on-a-anchor-link)