# Session can't be updated when trigger button used jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, session

when i click on a button that tries to modify the session's value on serverside, it runs very well:

```
$('#btn1').click(function() {
   update_session('session.php?session=1');
});
```

But when i tried to trigger this button from another button:

```
$('#btn2').click(function() {
   $('#btn1').click();
});
```

At that moment, the session isn't changed. I really don't understand because i saw in firebug that there was a POST to server by ajax with the correct arguments.

Comment: If there was a POST to the server, the client-side code works well. Then, the problem must be server side and it has nothing to do if you clicked the element or used `.click()`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be caused by the fact that [`.click()` does not execute the href attribute of an anchor tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577555/jquery-trigger-click-doesnt-work)

Having it this way should work:

```
var clicked = function() {
   update_session('session.php?session=1');
};
$('#btn1').click(clicked);
$('#btn2').click(clicked);
```

If it didn't work it is very likely a server side problem (as suggested by Oriol).