# Why can't I trigger the default href on another anchor with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm posting this because I can't find the same question elsewhere.

I'm trying to trigger the default action of an anchor but calling .click() or .trigger('click') in the click handler of another anchor.

Like so:

HTML:

```
<!-- I want to simulate a user clicking link2 when the user actually clicks link 1. -->
<!-- My guess is that triggering click just triggers any JS-bound click handlers. But that would defeat the point of e.preventDefault() when you usually have to call this to stop the default href being followed -->
<a id="link1" href="#">Click</a>
<a id="link2" target="_blank" href="http://google.com">Link 2</a>
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#link1').on('click', function(){
              $('#link2').click();
              $('#link2').trigger('click'); // Neither work
         });
    });
```

I feel like such a noob but nothing happens on click. Is this something that is blocked for security or accessibility?

I do not want to use window.open();

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0hggdkzb/

Comment: Do these links point to different pages?

Comment: It's actually working. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/0hggdkzb/11/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: trigger click() doesn't work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577555/jquery-trigger-click-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#link1').on('click', function(){
      // $('#link2').click().css('color','red');
        document.getElementById("link2").click();
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0hggdkzb/6/)**

Or

you can trigger event `$('#link2')[0].click();`

Comment: I thought by triggering a jQuery click that the event's last handler would be the browser's default action. Your solution works but triggering the click on the DOM element directly. Why?

Comment: Why use jQuery for some, but not the other?

Answer (score 1):

[Triggering-event-handlers](http://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/) clears about this,

> The *.trigger()* function cannot be used to mimic native browser events,
>   such as clicking on a file input box or an anchor tag. This is
>   because, there is no event handler attached using jQuery's event
>   system that corresponds to these events.
>
> The jQuery UI Team created [jquery.simulate.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-simulate/) in order to simplify
>   triggering a native browser event for use in their automated testing.
>   Its usage is modeled after jQuery's trigger.

```
$( "a" ).simulate( "click" );
```

And for your problem you have to use javascript core event as @Bala answered like,

```
$(function(){
    $('#link1').click(function(){
        $('#link2')[0].click();
    });
});
```

or use location.href like,

```
$(function(){
    $('#link1').click(function(){
        window.location = $('#link2').attr('href');
    });
});
```

Also, [Hoffman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1694803/1817690) gave the answer for the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#link1").click(function()
    {
      $('#link2')[0].click();
    });
});
```

Comment: This is not what I was asking.